# Why is javascript not supported in OAF?

Tags: javascript, oracle, frameworks, oracleapplications, application-framework

why is that it is not recommended to use Javascript in OA framework? Can we use javascript while extending the controller of a seeded oracle page?

Answer (score 1):

There is a RawTextBean (Similar Name) in OAF. While Extending the controller, add the RawTextBean programatically and keep your java script as the value of the bean.

This component will not go through the UIX layer processing so it gets added as is. Which will insert any of your HTML/CSS/Javascript changes.

Hope this helps.